# Which to use of ps ef or ps -ef?

Tags: ps

I see there is a difference in output between `ps ef` and `ps -ef`. What is that difference, are both commands correct or which is preferred?

Comment: `ps -ef` == `ps aux` afaik

Comment: a good explanation is here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1021905

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See `man ps` (the one on your system, on-line can have different explanations).

```
This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:

   1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
   2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
   3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

So the 1st method (`ps ef`) is BSD style and the manual page goes on with

> The use of BSD-style options **will add process state (stat=STAT) to the default
>          display and show the command args (args=COMMAND) instead of the executable
>          name**. You can override this with the PS_FORMAT environment variable. The use of
>          BSD-style options will also change the process selection to include processes
>          on other terminals (TTYs) that are owned by you; alternately, this may be
>          described as setting the selection to be the set of all processes filtered to
>          exclude processes owned by other users or not on a terminal. These effects are
>          not considered when options are described as being "identical" below, so -M
>          will be considered identical to Z and so on.

So both are valid commands but they are not showing the same information.

Answer (score 20):

[`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) says:

```
This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:

1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a
    dash.
2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a
    dash.
3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

So, `ef` uses the BSD `e` and `f` options, and `-ef` uses the Unix `-e` and `-f` options. These are different (sections `SIMPLE PROCESS SELECTION`, `OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL` and `OUTPUT MODIFIERS` respectively):

```
   -e     Select all processes.  Identical to -A.
   -f     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many
          other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also
          causes the command arguments to be printed.  When used with
          -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns
          will be added.  See the c option, the format keyword args, and
          the format keyword comm.

   e      Show the environment after the command.

   f      ASCII art process hierarchy (forest).
```

Clearly, you're not selecting all processes using the `ef` options, but are using the default listing of processes, plus some additional formatting:

```
By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID
(euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal
as the invoker.  It displays the process ID (pid=PID), the terminal
associated with the process (tname=TTY), the cumulated CPU time in
[DD-]hh:mm:ss format (time=TIME), and the executable name (ucmd=CMD).
Output is unsorted by default.

The use of BSD-style options will add process state (stat=STAT) to
the default display and show the command args (args=COMMAND) instead
of the executable name.  You can override this with the PS_FORMAT
environment variable. The use of BSD-style options will also change
the process selection to include processes on other terminals (TTYs)
that are owned by you; alternately, this may be described as setting
the selection to be the set of all processes filtered to exclude
processes owned by other users or not on a terminal.
```

Which should you use? What do you want to do with the output?

Also, see the [`EXAMPLES`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#EXAMPLES) section (which does list `-ef` rather prominently, and doesn't use the BSD `e` option at all):

```
EXAMPLES

   To see every process on the system using standard syntax:
      ps -e
      ps -ef
      ps -eF
      ps -ely

   To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:
      ps ax
      ps axu

   To print a process tree:
      ps -ejH
      ps axjf
```